# sass / scss create mixin for animations

Tags: sass, mixins

Hi I have some CSS and JS code to create a slide in effect when a user scrolls down the page and the element comes into view. I just wondered if someone could help explain how I would create a mixin to allow the value to change.

My HTML element would be like this

```
<div class="animation-element slide-left"></div>
```

My current CSS is this

```
.animation-element {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.animation-element.slide-left {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

My JS is

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

I would like to be able to pass a variable $distance which would be dynamic to change the 100 / distance the element slides in from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the `$distance` var from JS to a SASS mixin?

Comment: Can it not be done in sass? Everything works as it is but if I wanted to change the distance i.e. -100px to -200px for a different element I would have to write the whole css out again and give it a new class. I didn't know if it was possible to just pass in the distance variable  through the sass? That way I could have one block of code and just change the distance for each element?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you can pass a variable to a mixin, but as far as I know, you cannot pass a variable from JS to SASS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

I have removed the reference to using Compass as it is no longer being supported. If you're interested in an auto prefixer for SASS look into using [PostCss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) as you can require an [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) plugin.

---

You can pass variables to mixins in SASS. However, as I mentioned in my comment, I am not aware of a way to pass a variable to SASS through JS.

```
@mixin my-animation($distance) {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
    transform: translate3d($distance, 0, 0);
}

div {
    @include my-animation(-100px);
}
```

<strike>I do recommend using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). If you import Compass, `@import 'compass';`, and use `@include transform(..);` it will auto-prefix the transform property for you saving you from writing a few lines of code as well.</strike>

If you want to use JS to modify the `distance` value, you could use JS to add an inline style with the transform property you want including your custom `distance` value.

```
$('.your-element').css({'transform': 'translate3d('+distance+', 0, 0)'});
```

Comment: Not tried it yet but will when I get home. It looks like the sort of thing I was hoping for. No need to do it I'm JS I'll just pass the distance in sass on the div like you have. Thanks once I've tried it I'll approve the comment.

Comment: Forgot to reply but this worked perfect. I used gulp autoprefixer instead of compass but works a treat. Thank you